# Pourquoi dit-on montant et somme pour désigner une quantité d'argent ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Les mots « somme » et « montant » ont tous les deux quelque chose à voir avec la hauteur. Le lien entre « montant » et la hauteur va de soi. Le mot « somme » est issu du latin *summa*, une conjugaison de *altus*, *haut*, si je ne me trompe pas. Même le mot anglais *amount* provient du français *amont*. Je ne sais pas s'il y a d'autres exemples, mais ces trois mots sont assez pour me faire réfléchir à quelle est la racine de cet ensemble de mots.

Je ne vois aucune liaison entre *haut* et l'argent. J'espère qu'il y a quelqu'un qui peut me dire pourquoi ça marche comme ça.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tout s'explique quand on sait que les Romains comptaient de bas en haut : la *suma linea* désignait le total formé par la réunion des éléments d'un compte et, par extension, une somme d'argent, une totalité, un ensemble.

Le mot « somme » est le résultat de l'évolution de deux mots latins, *sume* et *some*, issu par évolution phonétique du latin classique *summa*, abréviation de *suma linea* qui veut dire la « la ligne du sommet, ligne d'en haut ». Le mot latin *summa* est le féminin de *summus* (accusatif *summum*), qui est le point le plus haut et qui a donné le mot « sommet » en français.

Le mot « montant » vient du verbe « monter » du latin *montare* (dérivé de *mons*, élévation, hauteur) qui signifiait « aller vers le haut ». Le nom anglais *amount* vient du verbe *amount* du vieil anglais *amounten* du vieux français *[amonter](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/amonter)* issu du latin *montare*.

À ma connaissance il n'y a aucun rapport avec la racine mot « haut » (du latin *altus*, participe passé de *alere* « nourrir, faire grandir ») et la *suma linea*, si ce n'est que par périphrase la ligne du sommet est bien celle qui se trouve en haut. Le lien est sémantique, pas étymologique.

<sup>Source sur les données étymologiques : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey, ed. Le Robert.</sup>

Comment: Peut-être que je me trompe complètement, mais à la base je voyais plus la somme et le montant dans le même sens que "l'addition" i.e addition = SOMME de toutes les choses conSOMMEES dans un endroit vendant des biens à conSOMMation immédiate. De plus le montant viendrait du fait que l'addition ne peut qu'augmenter lorsque l'on achète plusieurs choses. Me trompe-je?

Answer (score 0):

Amount > montant. Same origin.

Sum > Somme. Same origin. 
Montant will often go with a number : acheter .X..pour un montant de 500.O00 €.

You can say acheter .X.. pour la somme de 500.000 €, which feels a bit more like a total, a sum, rather than just a figure.

You can play with them in combination with adjectives not related to maths, without numbers: example « un montant exorbitant »; « des sommes folles » both meaning ludicrouly ... high amounts of money.

In terms of height, I would think that the two words have more to do with accounting and addition, and, like other answer said, the way the Romans were doing their sums.

Answer (score -1):

Je vois la liaison entre hauteur et argent ainsi :

[image]

Comment: Veuillez mettre votre réponse à jour avec plus de détails, en expliquant mieux l'objet de la réponse.